# How do I use data from the params array in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that passes several numbers to a method called calculate.  I need use those numbers to run through an equation and produce a result.

params.inspect produces the following output:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Mi7YZLMPbbYXozIE/XkC53Qhpck+kCihnp0sLuPSwEs=",     "braidcalc"=>{"braider_id"=>"6", "number_of_carriers"=>"24", "carrier_speed"=>"90", "capstan_diameter"=>"24", "core_diameter"=>"1", "wire_diameter"=>"1", "wire_material"=>"copper"}, "commit"=>"Run Calculation", "controller"=>"start", "action"=>"calculate"}

I can't seem to get the syntax right.  I know this example is far from correct syntax, but it should communicate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
def calculate (number_of_carriers, carrier_speed, capstan_diameter, core_diameter, wire_diameter)
  result = <calculation using numbers from params>
  return result
end
```

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and I'm translating an old application from Visual Basic to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `calculate` method is defined in the same controller then in this case you don't need to pass `params` as they are readily available and accessible within the controller.

Here is how `calculate` method should look:

```
def calculate 
  result = params[:braidcalc][:number_of_carriers].to_i + params[:braidcalc][:carrier_speed].to_i   ## perform calculations as per your requirement
  return result
end
```

You call it from any other action from the same controller using:

```
def action_name
    result = calculate
    ....
end
```

Comment: Thank you Kirti!  I'm still getting used to the abundant use of colons in Ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you can do:

```
braidcalc = params[:braidcalc]
result = calculate(braidcalc[:number_of_carriers], braidcalc[:carrier_speed], braidcalc[:capstan_diameter], braidcalc[:core_diameter], braidclac[:wire_diameter])
```

in your method:

```
def calculate (number_of_carriers, carrier_speed, capstan_diameter, core_diameter, wire_diameter)
  result = number_of_carrier.to_i + carrier_speed.to_i # or whatever
  return result
end
```